# Object vs Condition, wait() vs await()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, reentrantlock

In the solution to an programming exercise concerning locks, I've noticed they were using an Object to syncronize on, so something like:

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
Object obj = new Object();
```

and in a method:

```
synchronized(obj){
obj.wait();}
```

my question is, could I have used a Condition instead, let's say:

```
Condition cond = lock.newCondition();
```

and then use, in the method,

```
cond.await()
```

instead, without putting it in a synhronized block?

edit: the solution:
[image]

How would I implement this with the Condition?

Comment: Yes they are two different language tools, you can use to solve the same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. But you have to aquire the lock first. See the doc of [Condition.await()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await()):

> The current thread is assumed to hold the lock associated with this
>   Condition when this method is called. It is up to the implementation
>   to determine if this is the case and if not, how to respond.
>   Typically, an exception will be thrown (such as
>   IllegalMonitorStateException) and the implementation must document
>   that fact.

```
synchronized (obj) {
    while (<condition does not hold>)
        obj.wait();
    ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
}
```

is similar with

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
Condition cond = lock.newCondition();
lock.lock();
try {
    while (<condition does not hold>)
        cond.await();
    }       
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I still have a question, that's why I uploaded a picture of the solution in my question. I'm not sure how I'd have to implement that code using Condition...